# Як наші пращури називали туалет?

Tags: запозичені-слова

Оскільки слово *туалет* має французьке походження, можна здогадатися, що раніше мало існувати питомо українське слово на позначення цього терміна.

Спочатку спало на думку *вбиральня*. Та цього слова зась відшукати в [словникові Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com), а [СУМ подає цитати](http://sum.in.ua/s/ubyraljnja) вживання в цьому значенні лише з 20 століття. То як же в старі часи українці називали туалет?

Comment: Спробуй пошукати потрібний відповідник для запозиченого слова "туалет" на Словотворі: https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/tualet

Comment: http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/56328-srach.html#show_point , http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/56325-sralnja.html#show_point

Answer (score 7):

[Словарь российсько-український](https://r2u.org.ua/html/umanets_pered.html), що укладений М. Уманцем і А. Спілкою протягом 1893–1899 років, і який технічно належить до періоду **перед** ХХ століттям, на запит *нужник* видає у якості варіантів [*паску́дник, сра́ч*](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=9&highlight=on).

Не впевнений щодо того коли саме українці почали вживати ці слова і чи це були "старі часи", але вищезазначений словник є найстарішим джерелом, яке зміг знайти.

Comment: Вітаємо на сайті! Бачу, ви вже одразу зорієнтувалися щодо формату відповідей. Сподіваємось на подальшу співдискусію. Наснаги!

Answer (score 3):

Ось, знайшов таке:

[image]

І дійсно, у Грінченка:

> **Сральня, ні, сратва, ви,** *ж.* = Срач. Не йди туди, бо то панська сратва. Лубен. у.
> **Срач, ча,** *м.* Ретирадъ, нужникъ, отхожее мѣсто. Макс. (1849) 69.

Answer (score 2):

На Галичині люди народжені на початку ХХст. й досі вживають слово "віходок". По походженню цеслово, скоріш за все, є суто слов'янським, воно має аналог в чеській "záchod"[заход] та російській: "отхожее место", місце куди відходять. Такий термін міг виникнути ще в справді старі часи до розповсюдження відокремлених будівель.